# Get JNLP file name from the launched program

Tags: java, filenames, jnlp

Is it possible to determine JNLP file name from the launched thru Web Start java program?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("jnlpx.origFilenameArg")
```

Comment: Perfect for my instance of this!  Gets the locally cached JNLP name rather than the remote, so may not fit all needs.

Answer (score 1):

At he moment, the only way I know how to do that is to add a `property` with the JNLP href as the value.  The application can add that to `BasicService.getCodeBase()` to construct the URL to the JNLP file.

---

Why do you need this information?

> It's necessary for statistic needs.

If you want to determine hits on the JNLP, those will be revealed in the server logs.
If it is necessary to determine 'number of successful launches', then add the `HREF` into the JNLP as a `property` and have each app. reach back to the server (to an 'app. phone home' page) once it is started.

Comment: It's necessary for statistic needs. However, the whole url is not necessary for me, just file name will be enough.